# How to determine transitive relation with union-find

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, union-find

I have the following data sets

```
6 - 7  -->means 6 and 7 are related
5 - 4  -->means 5 and 4 are related
4 - 6  -->means 4 and 6 are related
```

now how do i determine if 5 is related to 7 using union-find? Someone please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use `Union-Find` here. You can use a basic `DFS` marking each visited vertex in one connected component with the index of the vertex from which you started `DFS` in this component. This method is linear in terms of the input sizes, so it is always faster than any implementation of `Union-Find`.

However, if you want to do it by `Union-Find`, for each edge `x-y` in your input, call `Union(x, y)`. After processing all the edges, if you want to find out if a vertex a is related to `a` vertex `b`, i.e. if there is a sequence of vertices connected by edges starting with `a` and ending with `b`, just check if `Find(a) == Find(b)`. The complexity of this method depends on how you implement the Union-Find data structure. The best implementation achieves almost linear time, which is in practice consider as linear algorithm.